# Template Building

Tags: php, codeigniter

Working with the [Template Library Here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/index.html#install) and am still a little confused on where I'm supposed to store my header and footer files and how they are formed still.

Controller:

```
class Kowmanager extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->library('template');
    parent::__construct();

}

function index()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['user_id']    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username']   = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }
}

}

/* End of file kowmanager.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/kowmanager.php */
```

What I want to happen is have the header and footer files load and then also have it to where it'll load the active model because there's' login and there's register and others but those will have its own content and it'll be loaded in between the header and footer.

Edit: I'm just confused on where to put the header footer files

Does anyone have any ideas with this?

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: updated with new content just keep in mind of the library i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to load a view between a header and footer?

I had the same problem, and finally came up with the idea to use a library to do the rendering.

What I did was create a file`libraries/render.php` with something like:

```
class render
{
    private $CI;
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI &= get_instance();
    }
    function view ($activeView, $params, $title)
    {
        $this->CI->load->view('template/header.php', array('title'=>$title));
        $this->CI->load->view($activeView, $params);
        $this->CI->load->view('template/footer.php', array('navbar'=>$this->RenderFooterNavBar()));
    }

    private function RenderFooterNavBar ()
    {
        $bits = array('Home','About Us', 'Contact'); //You could get these from anywhere
        return $this->CI->load->view('template/modules/footernavbar', array('bits'=>$bits), TRUE); //returns the rendered output of that view
    }
}
```

With the files like:
`template/header.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

`template/footer.php`:

```
</body>
</html>
```

`template/modules/footernavbar`

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($bits as $item)
    echo "<li>$item</li>";
?>
</ul>
```

Then to use:

```
function index ()
{
    $this->render->view('post', $data, 'Blog Post');
}
```

Note, this should work with any templating system, just tweak the `load->view`s with what your templating system uses.  This is also a great way to render data that a header/footer needs, if you want to pull things from a database, just mirror what I did with the `RenderFooterNavBar ()` function.

Hope that helps some,
Max

Comment: I had downloaded the template system from here http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show  but not sure if I am understanding it